# CoreCLR, 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetTypeFromProgID'

Tags: c#, dnx, coreclr

I'm trying to upgrade a web application from dnx451 to a dotnetcoreapp1.0.

This application needs to use an old library (at least I think it's a library). This snippet used to work with DNX, but it doesn't now that I've upgraded.

```
//COMPILE ERROR: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetTypeFromProgID'
var comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ABCCrypto2.Crypto"); 

var abc = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);

var license = _config["AbcCrypto:License"];
var password = _config["AbcCrypto:Password"];

comType.InvokeMember("License", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, abc, new object[] { license });
comType.InvokeMember("Password", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, abc, new object[] { password });

var hashed = comType.InvokeMember("Encrypt", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, abc, new object[] { data });
```

Any ideas or workarounds? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The code above is in *a class library separate from the ASP.NET Core Web Application that references it*. Here is the project.json for the class library:

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": false
},
"dependencies": {
    "MyApp.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "System.Net.Mail": "1.0.0-rtm-00002",
    "System.Runtime": "4.1.0"
},
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": { }
}
```

And here is the project.json for the ASP.NET Core Web Application:

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
},
"dependencies": {
    "MyApp.Services": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
},
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                "type": "platform",
                "version": "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
},
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x86": {}
}
```

Comment: You asked for more "core".  Nobody enjoys running a registry cleaner on their phone.  Or Linux.  Using .NETCore doesn't make any sense at all when you have a dependency on a component that can only ever work on a Windows install.  Just target the full version of .NET, it is always available on such a machine.

Comment: @HansPassant I changed my framework to net461 and that seemed to fix this error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`Type.GetTypeFromProgID` exist if you will add `"System.Runtime": "4.1.0"` to dependencies section in your project.json file.

If you want to check if some api exist and where it exist use [apisof.net](https://apisof.net/).

Anyway, as Hans wrote, maybe you should not target net core at all..

Comment: I added "System.Runtime": "4.1.0" but it didn't fix the error. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @johnluke Can you show me the project.json file? The restore command sucsseded? I just tried it with new coreapp project and it work.

Comment: I added the project.json files. dotnet restore works for both the class library and the core web app. However, I still get the same original error.

Comment: I posted an answer. Thanks for your help Dudi.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my framework to net461 and it worked. And I can still use the AspNetCore packages:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": {}
}
```

However, I now have a problem related to loading the COM library, but I think it's a separate error, so I'll post a new question.